# Logically solving Java Security Error

Tags: java, security, applet, mixed-code

When I open up applet I see the below security warning/error.

[image]

I have googled and found the solution from http://java.com/en/download/help/error_mixedcode.xml saying to edit the options from settings. Its valid but my clients can never understand this.

Just want to confirm, Can we get ride of this by adding anything in applet/object tag or are there any other ways. Please help me out on this.

Answer (score 3):

The page linked in the question is for end users, for developers see the real fix at [Mixing Privileged Code and Sandbox Code: Securely Deploying Privileged Applications and Applets Without a Mixed Code Warning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html#manifest).

Comment: Thanks for the response Andrew.. Trying it out. Will let you know shortly.

Comment: OK, I just took a very long time to sort out that I am doing a right thing. When Adding "Trusted-Library: true" in MANIFEST.MF file then jar's getting classNoFoundException. Even I have tried to update the jar's using ant build. Still I get the same error.

Comment: From the below link I can see that user removed the 'Trusted-Library' attribute to get things work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084324/java-applet-stopped-working-after-update-to-jre-7u21?rq=1 that happens with the latest java update