# Java web applet fails to start in Java 1.7.0_21

Tags: java, applet

We have Java applets deployed that have worked fine up until now. Actually, they continue to run fine on 32 bit machines, but on 64 bit machines they stopped yesterday.

The last line of the error is...

Match: Running JVM args mismatch: have:<-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true> !satisfy want:<>

Here is the .jnlp file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp href="app.jnlp">
<!--<jnlp codebase="http://www.url.edu/directory" href="app.jnlp">-->
<information>
<title>App via Web Start</title>
<vendor>School</vendor>
<homepage href="http://www.url.edu"/>
<description>Application</description>
<description kind="short">Application</description>
<offline-allowed/>
</information>

<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>

<resources>
<j2se version="1.5+"/>
<property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
<!-- your jar files -->
<jar href="v0.41/CC.jar" main="true"/>
<!-- Core jars -->
<extension name="pCSDT-Core" href="../Core/v0.41/Core.jnlp" />
<!-- OpenGL extensions -->
<extension name="java3d-latest" href="../media/java3d/webstart/release/java3d-latest.jnlp"/>
<extension name="jogl" href="../media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-1.x-webstart-current/jogl.jnlp"/>
<extension name="gluegen-rt" href="../media/gluegen/webstart/gluegen-rt.jnlp" />
</resources>

  <applet-desc name="pCSDT Applet" main-class="CC.CCGui" width="1200" height="800">
  </applet-desc>

</jnlp>
```

Apparently, it's the properties tag above that is the problem. I've tried removing it and then I get a null error. I have read where the `.jnlp` file needs to be signed (by placing a copy of the `.jnlp` file in the `.jar`), that hasn't fixed it.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the instructions to copy the .jnlp file into the jar?

Comment: Which os r u using. If mac then it will not run as oracle does not produce 32 bit vm now

Comment: Hi - thanks! On 32bit Windows os, applets still load fine. On 64bit Windows I get the error above. Here is the link that I found and used (didn't work however)....

Comment: Sorry, I can't find the original link (I've looked many places), but here's a link that talks about signing a .jnlp file...http://www.coderanch.com/t/554729/JNLP-Web-Start/java/Signing-JNLP-JNLP-INF-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot launch applet using Java 7u21](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083405/cannot-launch-applet-using-java-7u21) or [Java applet stopped working after update to JRE 7u21](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16084324/418556).  Please search before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

1. First at all : **Test if other applet run on the browser**.
    [Check the installation from the Java site (Oracle)](http://www.java.com/fr/download/installed.jsp)
2. **The test fail**, the content of the applet doesn't come. It it means that none applet can run on this browser : you need to install the correct jvm for the browser. For firefox or chrome you need a 32bit jvm.
   If you have a IE64 then you need to install jvm 64. You can install both 32 and 64 without problem. That's what I have done on my machine :
   [Download the java 64 bits version](http://www.java.com/fr/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml)
   **There is no way to avoid this step !**
3. The test is ok, then the problem is in your applet. I have no idea of the cause, you have to search, look at the possible duplicates in the comment.

ps.: Please if step 2 solve the problem tag my answer. But if you fail in case 3, don't add comment on this question. Make research, open a chat or make a new question, stackoverflow should not be interractive.

Comment: We have multiple applets that used to work, and now they don't, giving the error above. I've tested in Chrome, IE and FF (the problem seems to be limited to Windows 64bit 7 & 8.

Comment: Check if you have the correct install with this link http://www.java.com/fr/download/installed.jsp

Comment: Thank you mki. I think we're especially concerned that potential users of the software with 64bit machines, without 32bit browsers installed will try to use the software and have it not load, and then give up. It used to work on 64bit machines just fine, and now it doesn't.